# How to insert a video into frame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXOGpw)

**CODE:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.embed-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  max-width: 1062px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1062px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.weltpixel.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/Magento_2_Theme_Pearl_Demo_9.png" alt="Magento 2 Theme Demo 6">


  <div class='embed-container'><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OUGB5dqKgpE?autoplay=1&loop=1&cc_load_policy=1rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&playlist=OUGB5dqKgpE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to insert the video into that frame and be responsive as in the example below.
How can I position that item where I want it?

Can you help me find a solution please?

Thanks in advance!

[example](https://www.screencast.com/t/Tf50hyik)

Answer (score 0):

You can change style as per snippet I have provided :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.embed-container {
  width:40%;
  position:absolute;
  top:290px;
  left:270px;
  max-width:1062px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1062px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.weltpixel.com/pub/media/wysiwyg/Magento_2_Theme_Pearl_Demo_9.png" alt="Magento 2 Theme Demo 6">


  <div class='embed-container'><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OUGB5dqKgpE?autoplay=1&loop=1&cc_load_policy=1rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&playlist=OUGB5dqKgpE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
</div>
```